# When creating a dynamic checkbox list i can't receive data from service (observable)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-observable

In the service I receive all the records from the firebase database with this function.:

```
treatmentsRef:  AngularFireList<any>;
treatments$: Observable<any[]>;

receiveTreatment(){
    this.treatmentsRef = this.db.list('/treatments');
    this.treatments$ = this.treatmentsRef.valueChanges();

    return this.treatments$;
}
```

Next i call this function in my component to fill the array:

```
treatments= [];

constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, protected CashdeskService: CashdeskService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, public settings: SettingsService) { 

    this.settings.receiveTreatment().subscribe( res => this.treatments = res);
    console.log(this.treatments);
    const formControls = this.treatments.map(control => new FormControl(false));
    this.musicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        treatments: new FormArray(formControls)
    });
}
```

When i console.log the subscribe everything shows fine but when i try to subscribe to this.treatments nothing happen. I need this to work because all they treatments will be shown in a dynamic checkbox from which structured like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="musicForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <label formArrayName="treatments" *ngFor="let desc of musicForm.controls.treatments.controls; let i = index" style="width: 100%">
         <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
         {{treatments[i].desc}}
    </label><br>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Is there anyone who knows the solution? or a easier way to create a dynamic list based on the values of an array.

Comment: please create a stackblitz demo for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recommend doing all of what you do in `ngOnInit()` and not in the constructor,
then, whatever you wanna do with the value you subscribe to, should be done within your subscribe(). Try something like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.settings.receiveTreatment().subscribe( 
    res => { 
      this.treatments = res
      console.log(this.treatments);
      const formControls = this.treatments.map(control => new FormControl(false));
      this.musicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        treatments: new FormArray(formControls)
      });
    }
  );
}
```